# page as intermediary

Tags: php, html, sql, header

my main page have search feature. after input the search item, i use post method that lead to search page. the search.php file, will load and find search item submitted from main page in database and redirect to a specific page. this header i use that wished work but definitely not

```
header("Location: veDetail.php?vePlate='".$r['vePlate']."' ");
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work, what does it do?

Comment: it display blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it now it redirects to `veDetail.php?vePlate='XYZ'`. Change your code to

`header("Location: veDetail.php?vePlate={$r['vePlate']}");`

to redirect to `veDetail.php?vePlate=XYZ`